# Showing each step geocode of directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, map-directions

**Google Maps API** can build a Direction from a source to a destination.  In the following Google's example, each step are published into the HTML code: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/directions-simple.html

I would like to get the Geocoding of each step of this direction, and store them in a array. I believe it's possible, but I don't see how to process.

Many Thanks for any answer.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get the individual steps from [GDirections](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections) very easily.

First you have to make sure to pass the `getSteps: true` option when you call the `GDirections.load()` method. Then you can simply iterate through `GDirections.getRoute(i).getStep(j)`, as in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Simple Directions Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
              type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()">
   <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 400px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      var directions = new GDirections(map);

      directions.load('from: London, UK to: Glasgow, UK', { getSteps: true });

      GEvent.addListener(directions, "load", function() {
         if (directions.getNumRoutes() > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < directions.getRoute(0).getNumSteps(); i++) {
               directions.getRoute(0).getStep(i).getLatLng().lat();
               directions.getRoute(0).getStep(i).getLatLng().lng();
               directions.getRoute(0).getStep(i).getDescriptionHtml();
               directions.getRoute(0).getStep(i).getPolylineIndex();
               directions.getRoute(0).getStep(i).getDistance().meters;
               directions.getRoute(0).getStep(i).getDuration().seconds;
            }
         }
      });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Further reading and reference:

- [GDirections](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections)
- [GRoute](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GRoute)
- [GStep](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GStep)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel Vassallo! Just awesome example! Very helpful.